# IBM Worklight - What are the circumstances that might lead to "onInitWebFrameworkComplete" not getting a callback?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

We have an IBM Worklight Android application where our class extends CordovaActivity and implements WLInitWebFrameworkListener.

According to worklight documentation we initialised the following in onCreate()

```
WL.createInstance(this);

WL.getInstance().initializeWebFramework(getApplicationContext(), this);
```

However there are certain times where we are seeing

```
public void onInitWebFrameworkComplete(WLInitWebFrameworkResult result) {}
```

is not getting called, and hence we are seeing blank pages.
Its intermittent and not reproducible everytime.

Comment: Which version of MFP is being used? Please provide more details.

Comment: I am on 7.0.0 version of MFP, and this issue is mostly reproducible during first launch.upgrade scenarios.

Comment: So did you have to manually add the code to initialize? When we create a project in Studio using the Eclipse plugin the following code is auto generated 
`WL.createInstance(this);

WL.getInstance().initializeWebFramework(getApplicationContext(), this);`
I tried with the latest version of MFP 7.0 (7.0.0.0-MFPF-IF201701251125) the app works fine on  both cases. Please share a sample with the issue reproduced and share a link to the sample here.